# Why is my hosts file reseting on reboot?

Tags: ubuntu

I've setup a brand new linux machine with Ubuntu 8.04.  I've added a few hosts in `/etc/hosts` but upon reboot of the OS, the file is reset to its original content.  The original content looks like:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
# Auto-generated hostname. Please do not remove this comment.
00.00.0.000 myhost
```

I'm actually using a real ip number instead of the series of zero above.  Does anyone know how I can prevent my `hosts` file from being wiped after a reboot?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is real; it's the loopback address.  if you manage to get the hosts file to be persistent make sure you leave that line alone.  (speaking of persistent, you aren't booting into the LiveCD are you?)

Comment: Oh no, the OS is fully installed and booting from the hard drive.

Comment: thought so; just making sure.

Comment: ~quack: I think the "series of zero" line is `00.00.0.000`, not the loopback line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the answer is in my question, I just deleted the comment and the file is not overwritten on reboot, I deleted the following line:

```
# Auto-generated hostname. Please do not remove this comment.
```

Comment: that's it??  remove the comment and whatever it is stops resetting the file?  how bizarre.